# Linq generic GroupBy date and other fields at the same time

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to be able to group some database results by year/month/week/day as well as other properties at the same time using Linq. The user should be able to switch between grouping by year/month/week/day at runtime. The typical situation is that i have some kind of DTO containing a `DateTime` timestamp as well as other properties.

UPDATE: I found a working solution. See post below.

For grouping only by date (excluding grouping by other properties), I have created a `DateGroupKey` class and an extension method:

**DateGroupKey class**

```
public class DateGroupKey
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

**Extension method**

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateGroupKey, TValue>> GroupByDate<TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TValue> source,
        Func<TValue, DateTime> dateSelector,
        DateGroupType dateGroupType)
{
    Func<TValue, DateGroupKey> keySelector = null;
    switch (dateGroupType)
    {
            case DateGroupType.Year:
                keySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year };
                break;
            case DateGroupType.Month:
                keySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year, Month = dateSelector(val).Month };
                break;
            case DateGroupType.Week:
                keySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year, Week = dateSelector(val).GetIso8601WeekOfYear() };
                break;
            case DateGroupType.Day:
                keySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year, Month = dateSelector(val).Month, Day = dateSelector(val).Day };
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Group type not supported: {dateGroupType}");
    }

    return source.GroupBy(keySelector, new DateGroupKeyComparer());
}
```

where the `DateGroupKeyComparer` is a class implementing `IEqualityComparer<DateGroupKey>`. I can use the extension method like this:

```
var grouped = results.GroupByDate<ProductDto>(x => x.TimeStamp, DateGroupType.Month)
```

which works as it should. Now, I would like to expand on this idea and be able to group not only by date but also some of the other fields at the same time. Say the `ProductDto`class has the following signature

```
public class ProductDto
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp {get; set;}
    public int ProductGroup {get; set;}
    public int Variant {get; set;}
    public double Value {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to do something along the lines of

```
var grouped = results.GroupByDate<ProductDto>(x => x.TimeStamp, x => x.ProductGroup, x => x.Variant, DateGroupType.Month);
```

but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to aproach this. I thought about abstracting the `DateGroupKey` into an `IDateGroupKey` interface holding the Year, Month, Week and Day properties, and somehow tell the GroupBy extension how to map to this specific implementation, but I am not sure whether it is the right  (or simplay 'a') way to go.

Any good ideas of how to aproach this?

Comment: Would something like this not fit your needs (pseudocode):
`results.GroupBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.ProductGroup).ThenBy(x => x.Variant)`

Have a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: For me, this looks like pure  [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This is related to ordering - not grouping? Or did i miss something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a working solution - I am not quite satisfied but it will do for now.

I have created a generic composite key, holding a `DateGroupKey` object containing information on the date-grouping as well as a generic object key (to identity grouping fields not part of the date)

```
public class DateGroupCompositeKey<TKey>
{
    public DateGroupKey DateKey { get; set; }
    public TKey ObjectKey { get; set; }
}

public class DateGroupKey
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I implemented `IEqualityComparer` for these classes.

```
public class DateGroupKeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateGroupKey>
{
    public bool Equals(DateGroupKey x, DateGroupKey y)
    {
        return x.Year == y.Year &&
            x.Month == y.Month &&
            x.Week == y.Week &&
            x.Day == y.Day;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateGroupKey obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var h = 0;
            h = (h * 31) ^ obj.Year;
            h = (h * 31) ^ obj.Month;
            h = (h * 31) ^ obj.Week;
            h = (h * 31) ^ obj.Day;
            return h;
        }
    }
}

public class DateGroupCompositeKeyComparer<TValue> : IEqualityComparer<DateGroupCompositeKey<TValue>>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TValue> _valueComparer;
    private readonly DateGroupKeyComparer _dgkComparer;

    public DateGroupCompositeKeyComparer(IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueComparer)
    {
        _valueComparer = valueComparer;
        _dgkComparer = new DateGroupKeyComparer();
    }

    public bool Equals(DateGroupCompositeKey<TValue> x, DateGroupCompositeKey<TValue> y)
    {
        return _dgkComparer.Equals(x.DateKey, y.DateKey) &&
            _valueComparer.Equals(x.ObjectKey, y.ObjectKey);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateGroupCompositeKey<TValue> obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int h = 0;
            h = (h * 31) ^ _dgkComparer.GetHashCode(obj.DateKey);
            h = (h * 31) ^ _valueComparer.GetHashCode(obj.ObjectKey);
            return h;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my extension method(s) look like

```
public static class Extensions
{
    // This was the original extension
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateGroupKey, TValue>> GroupByDate<TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TValue> source, 
        Func<TValue, DateTime> dateSelector,
        DateGroupType dateGroupType)
    {
        Func<TValue, DateGroupKey> keySelector = DateKeySelector(dateSelector, dateGroupType);
        return source.GroupBy(keySelector, new DateGroupKeyComparer());
    }

    // New extension method supporting composite grouping
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateGroupCompositeKey<TKey>, TValue>> GroupByDateComposite<TKey, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TValue> source,
        Func<TValue, DateTime> dateSelector,
        Func<TValue, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer,
        DateGroupType dateGroupType)
    {
        var dateKeySelector = DateKeySelector(dateSelector, dateGroupType);

        DateGroupCompositeKey<TKey> func(TValue val) => 
            new DateGroupCompositeKey<TKey>
            {
                DateKey = dateKeySelector(val),
                ObjectKey = keySelector(val)
            };

        return source.GroupBy(func, new DateGroupCompositeKeyComparer<TKey>(keyComparer));
    }

    private static Func<TValue, DateGroupKey> DateKeySelector<TValue>(Func<TValue, DateTime> dateSelector, DateGroupType dateGroupType)
    {
        Func<TValue, DateGroupKey> dateKeySelector = null;
        switch (dateGroupType)
        {
            case DateGroupType.Year:
                dateKeySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year };
                break;
            case DateGroupType.Month:
                dateKeySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year, Month = dateSelector(val).Month };
                break;
            case DateGroupType.Week:
                dateKeySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year, Week = dateSelector(val).GetIso8601WeekOfYear() };
                break;
            case DateGroupType.Day:
                dateKeySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year, Month = dateSelector(val).Month, Day = dateSelector(val).Day };
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Group type not supported: {dateGroupType}");
        }
        return dateKeySelector;
    }

}
```

The extension can now be used (as in the original post, by grouping only by date)

```
var grouped = results.GroupBy<ProductDto>(x => x.TimeStamp, DateGroupType.Month);
```

or in the composite version

```
var grouped = results.GroupByDateComposite<int, ProductDto>(
    x => x.TimeStamp,
    x => x.ProductGroup,
    EqualityComparer<int>.Default,
    DateGroupType.Month);
```

The downside, as far as I can tell, is that for more complicated groupings, say

```
var grouped = results.GroupByDateComposite<CustomKey, ProductDto>(
    x => x.TimeStamp,
    x => new CustomKey{ ProductGroup = x.ProductGroup, Variant = x.Variant},
    new CustomKeyComparer(),
    DateGroupType.Month);
```

i would need to create seperate key classes and corresponding `IEqualityComparer` implementations to be able to do the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you need to do something like this:

my model class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(DateTime date, string name, int partNumber)
    {
        Date = date;
        Name = name;
        PartNumber = partNumber;
    }
    public DateTime Date { get;}

    public string Name { get;  }

    public int PartNumber {get;}
}
```

extension method to get week number:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static int WeekNumber(this DateTime date)
    {
        var cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        var week = cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        return week;
    }
}
```

and then grouping.

```
            var dataBase = new[]{
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2018,1,1),"Jane",10),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2017,1,1),"Jane",1),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2016,1,1),"Jane",10),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2018,2,1),"Jane",1),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2018,2,2),"Jane",10),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2017,2,2),"Jane",1),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2016,2,2),"Jane",10),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2018,2,8),"Jane",1),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2017,2,8),"Jane",10),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2016,2,8),"Jane",1),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2018,3,1),"Jane",10),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2017,3,1),"Jane",1),
            new MyClass(new DateTime(2016,3,1),"Jane",10),
        };

        var myCollection = new MyClasses(dataBase);

                    while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group By What");
            var type = Console.ReadLine();

            var enumType = (MyClasses.GroupType) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyClasses.GroupType), $"GroupBy{type.UppercaseFirst()}");

            foreach (var g in myCollection.GetGroupedValue(enumType))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(g.Key);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can create your own collection that will do what you would like. It could look something like this:

```
public class MyClasses : Collection<MyClass>
    {
        public enum GroupType
        {
            GroupByYear = 0,
            GroupByMonth = 1,
            GroupByWeek = 2
        }
        public MyClasses(IEnumerable<MyClass> classes)
        {
            foreach (var myClass in classes)
            {
                Add(myClass);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, MyClass>> GroupByYear => this.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Year);

        public IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, MyClass>> GroupByMonth => this.GroupBy(x => new { x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month});

        public IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, MyClass>> GroupByWeek => this.GroupBy(x => new { x.Date.Year, x.Date.WeekNumber()});

        public IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, MyClass>> GetGroupedValue(GroupType groupType)
        {
            var propertyName = groupType.ToString();
            var property = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            return property?.GetValue(this) as IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, MyClass>>;
        }
    }
```

this will group by the date requirements that you are asking for.

Update:

Comment: Thanks for your input - however, this will group by day. What I am looking for is the possibility of switching 'grouping mode' at runtime, i.e. from grouping by month to grouping by week (thus the DateGroupType enum). I am sorry, if this wasn't clear from the original post.

Comment: So just to make sure that I understand what you're saying is that you would like the user to be able to switch between day month year week?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: There are multiple issues here. First of all, grouping will be wrong if the timespan is several years. For instance, Jan. 2018 will be grouped together with Jan. 2017 and so forth. Secondly, a collection implementation would be needed for every Dto type which scales pretty badly. A solution to this could be to let all Dto's implement an 'ITimestamped' interface holding the DateTime property and then implement a single Collection<ITimestamped>, however this would leave me with the original problem of grouping not only on date, but also other properties of the different Dto's.

Comment: I'm currently fiddling with a possible solution with a 'composite grouping key'-kind of thing - i will post back, whether i succeed or not :)

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't solve the issues mentioned in the second part.

Comment: If you need a Dto, why cant you do `myCollection.Select(x=> new Dto(x.Date, x.PartNumber)); `