# Create a Linq to entities IQueryable extension for date grouping (GroupBy)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I am trying to build an expression tree for a custom grouping by date, transform this:

```
groupedData = entity.GroupBy(e => new DateTime(e.created_date.Year, 1, 1));
```

Into an extension that does not care what the source entity is. So far I have:

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<DateTime, TSource>> DateGroup<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, DateTime>> dateSelector, GraphDataTimeSpan span)
    {


        var year = Expression.Property(dateSelector.Body, nameof(DateTime.Year));

        var ctorinfo = typeof(DateTime).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int) });
        var ctroExp = Expression.New(ctorinfo, year, Expression.Constant(1), Expression.Constant(1));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, DateTime>>(ctroExp, dateSelector.Parameters);

        switch (span)
        {
            case GraphDataTimeSpan.Yearly:

                return source.GroupBy(lambda);

            case GraphDataTimeSpan.Monthly:

                break;
            case GraphDataTimeSpan.Weekly:

                break;
            case GraphDataTimeSpan.Daily:

                break;
        }


        return source.GroupBy(lambda);
    }
```

But it does not work at all, throwing an error:

[image: error]

Although it looked ok when I tried it on C# interactive console:

Expression.Lambda>(ctroExp, dateSelector.Parameters)

> [test => new DateTime(test.Created.Year, 1, 1)] { Body=[new DateTime(test.Created.Year, 1, 1)]

Comment: How do you call this extension? Like `entity.DateGroup(e => e.created_date, GraphDataTimeSpan.Yearly)`?

Comment: Yes, this will be part of something like context.Where().DateGroup().ToList()

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your code to:

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<DateTime, TSource>> DateGroup<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, DateTime> dateSelector, GraphDataTimeSpan span)
{
    switch (span)
    {
        case GraphDataTimeSpan.Yearly:
            return source.GroupBy(e => new DateTime(dateSelector(e).Year,1,1));
        case GraphDataTimeSpan.Monthly:
            return source.GroupBy(e => new DateTime(dateSelector(e).Year,dateSelector(e).Month,1));
        case GraphDataTimeSpan.Weekly:
            // TO DO
            break;
        case GraphDataTimeSpan.Daily:
            // TO DO
            break;
    }

    return source.GroupBy(e => dateSelector(e));
}
```

[Try it online](http://tpcg.io/vV9PWy)

With this data set:

```
List<Item> dates = new List<Item>{
    new Item(new DateTime(1901,1,1)),
    new Item(new DateTime(1902,1,1)),
    new Item(new DateTime(1902,2,1)),
    new Item(new DateTime(1903,4,1)),
    new Item(new DateTime(1902,1,2)),
    new Item(new DateTime(1905,1,3)),
    new Item(new DateTime(1907,2,1))
};
```

The following

```
foreach(var d in dates.AsQueryable().DateGroup(e => e.Date, GraphDataTimeSpan.Yearly))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.Key.ToString("yyyy"));
    foreach(var d2 in d)
        Console.WriteLine("  |"+d2.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}
```

Gives me:

```
1901
  |01/01/1901
1902
  |01/01/1902
  |01/02/1902
  |02/01/1902
1903
  |01/04/1903
1905
  |03/01/1905
1907
  |01/02/1907
```

And:

```
foreach(var d in dates.AsQueryable().DateGroup(e => e.Date, GraphDataTimeSpan.Monthly))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.Key.ToString("MM/yyyy"));
    foreach(var d2 in d)
        Console.WriteLine("  |"+d2.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}
```

Gives me:

```
01/1901
  |01/01/1901
01/1902
  |01/01/1902
  |02/01/1902
02/1902
  |01/02/1902
04/1903
  |01/04/1903
01/1905
  |03/01/1905
02/1907
  |01/02/1907
```

Comment: Does not work as the function has no translation to Sql, error: Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL. I don't have the data at this point yet

Comment: Would both `dateSelector(e)` and `dateSelector.Invoke(e)` lead to the same error? I currently can't test it with SQL

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around with something similar.
Maybe have a look at [Linq generic GroupBy date and other fields at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51192035/3337693)

I used a separate class for storing the grouping key.

```
public class DateGroupKey
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

The extension method looks like:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateGroupKey, TValue>> GroupByDate<TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TValue> source,
    Func<TValue, DateTime> dateSelector,
    DateGroupType dateGroupType)
{
    Func<TValue, DateGroupKey> keySelector = null;
    switch (dateGroupType)
    {
        case DateGroupType.Year:
            keySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year };
            break;
        case DateGroupType.Month:
            keySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year, Month = dateSelector(val).Month };
            break;
        case DateGroupType.Week:
            keySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year, Week = dateSelector(val).GetIso8601WeekOfYear() };
            break;
        case DateGroupType.Day:
            keySelector = val => new DateGroupKey { Year = dateSelector(val).Year, Month = dateSelector(val).Month, Day = dateSelector(val).Day };
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Group type not supported: {dateGroupType}");
    }

    return source.GroupBy(keySelector, new DateGroupKeyComparer());
}
```

And the equality comparer:

```
public class DateGroupKeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateGroupKey>
{
    public bool Equals(DateGroupKey x, DateGroupKey y)
    {
        return x.Year == y.Year &&
            x.Month == y.Month &&
            x.Week == y.Week &&
            x.Day == y.Day;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateGroupKey obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var h = 0;
            h = (h * 31) ^ obj.Year;
            h = (h * 31) ^ obj.Month;
            h = (h * 31) ^ obj.Week;
            h = (h * 31) ^ obj.Day;
            return h;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like

```
var grouped = results.GroupByDate<ProductDto>(x => x.TimeStamp, DateGroupType.Month);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `GroupBy` (in your usage) be `GroupByDate`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited my answer.

Comment: No, I realize that. Could be converted to expression but I am not sure how to tell EF how to convert that to SQL code.